# How do I monetize my PWA on play store (using TWA)

Tags: vue.js, google-play, progressive-web-apps, quasar-framework, twa

Good morning everyone, I am working on a Vuejs (Quasar) PWA and I intend to publish it on play store using TWA, my concern is with monetization through AdSense.
First of all, I need to place the google script in the head tag of my index.html for the site to be reviewed and approved, whoever/whatever responsible for reviewing the site will get stuck on the Login page because my app requires authentication. and I can not add any credentials for the reviewer to use because my AdSense account is not approved yet so the menu items are disabled.
Even if the account is approved somehow, I read somewhere on Google's support forum that its a violation of their policies to place ads on PWAs.
I want to know if its actually possible to monetize PWA's through AdSense, if so, how do I go about it (some links and resources would help), plus how do I get AdSense to approve my account when authentication is required to access my PWA?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

> I read somewhere on Google's support forum that its a violation of their policies to place ads on PWAs

AdSense ads are allowed in PWAs! I can think of several PWAs that include ads. The only complexity is how to show ads when/if the user is offline.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, well in my situation all i really care about is showing ads when users are online. With regards to the authentication, do you have any idea how that works??, i have a feeling my site would get rejected since there would be no content, only a login page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit late but I have been searching the same topic but until recently, I found a "solution", **[PropellerAds](https://propellerads.com/) (now [Monetag](https://monetag.com))**.

To be honest, it's quite fast to integrate, you just need to verify your site, add 2 lines of JavaScript code and that's all. Now, is it a good option to use PropellerAds? The answer is yes and no. You will get ads but they will look like these ones:

[image: example]

In my opinion, they can be tricky because they can bring a bad experience to your users, and in my case, they break my PWA normal behavior.

You might be wondering, does PropellerAds not offer you a kind of banner? Yes but only in very specific circumstances that my app doesn’t meet yet (a high traffic per month). Furthermore, there is no way to delete your account or channels easily, not even to change your email. Be careful if you go with this alternative.

I’d be very glad if anyone has another working solution or if you found an alternative and shared it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i rebuilt my app with flutter for some reasons and i am glad i did.